# Detecting 2.4 GHz signals using oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, spectrum-analyzer

I have used a spectrum analyzer with an antenna to see packets at 2.4 GHz being transmitted from my transceiver successfully. There was a mode in the spectrum analyzer which helps you to take a look at the power vs time plot too.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the same thing as above using a Tektronix TDS2024B Digital Storage Oscilloscope. As far as what I have understood about oscilloscope is that we need to use probes to connect it to the boards but how do I use it to detect these wireless packets?

Please excuse this naïve question.

Comment: At 2GSps you can't really do this.

Comment: Sadly an answer needs to have more than the two necessary chars of: no

Comment: A proble is a probe that is about to become a problem.

Comment: Maybe try a microwave Schottky diode into a 50 ohm resistor (or 50 ohm input) to see the envelope of the time domain signal.

Comment: To clarify about the scope/probe.  You can connect coax to a scope but you should tee at the scope and connect a 50 ohm termination.  This is fine for lower frequencies a scope uses.  Some scopes can select a 50 ohm impedance, too.  But your not going to have much luck at 2.4 GHz, at least not much usable info

Answer (score 1):

Not with just that oscilloscope.  You would need something with at least 2.4 GHz of bandwidth in order to see anything.

However, it is possible to combine several instruments.  One option would be to take a spectrum analyzer, put it in zero span, and feed the video out connection to an oscilloscope.  Another option would be to use a fast power meter (peak power meter) or crystal/diode detector and feed that to the scope.